# Difficulties with creating a 2D array and then writing it to a file (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

For a homework assignment, I need to create a class that that can read and write Byte arrays to/from a file. I have successfully created classes that can read and write CSV and text, however I am having some difficulty, when it comes to arrays.

I have written a method (writeByte - see below), that uses the FileOutput class (creates files, class can be found here http://www.devjavasoft.org/SecondEdition/SourceCode/Share/FileOutput.java).
I am getting stuck at the nested for loop. I need the for loop to allow the user to enter a series of integers that are separated by a tab.

When the following code is run I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method writeNewline() in the type FileOutput is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

---

I understand what this error message is saying to me, however when I try and create a new writeNewLine method in the FileOutput class, I am none the better. I am hoping that someone will be able to advise how I can rectify this problem. I am more than happy to not use the FileOutput class, I only used it as I have successfully created other file handling programs using it.

Kind regards

---

```
public void writeByte(final String fileNameOUT){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    FileOutput createData = new FileOutput (fileNameOUT);
    System.out.println("How many rows?");
    int rowsOut = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns?");
    int columnsOut = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Please enter data, separate each column with a tab.");


        String[] dataIn;
        int [] [] data = new int [rowsOut] [columnsOut];    
        String[] line = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsOut; i++){
                    line = createData.writeNewline(dataIn = input.nextLine().split("\t"));
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsOut; j++){
                data[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]); 
                System.out.print(data[i][j]);

            } 
        }   
        createData.close();

}
```

Comment: Do you have any particular spacing requirements?  I don't see why you're not just writing the line directly (as writing an array to file doesn't make much sense unless you're serializing the content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going over the code its clear that `writeNewline` doesn't have an argument. I think what you want to do is this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsOut; i++){
            createData.writeNewline();
            String lineString = input.nextLine();
            line = lineString.split("\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsOut; j++){
                data[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]); 
                System.out.print(data[i][j]);   
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I think I am nearly there. After implementing your code, I get the following error. Any ideas? Thanks so much Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.writeByte(ByteManager.java:59)
 at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.main(ByteManager.java:89)

Comment: You know what I was about to write that... You are expecting numbers in input Integer.parseInt(line[j]);.. If you pass string it will throw numberformatexception

Comment: Would I change lineString to be an int and take in ints? If so, how would I write the rest of the code? Many thanks!

Comment: Tried this: String[] dataIn;
   int [] [] data = new int [rowsOut] [columnsOut]; 
   String[] line = null;
 
   for (int i = 0; i < rowsOut; i++){
             createData.writeNewline();
             int lineString = input.nextInt();
            // line = lineString.split("\t");
             for (int j = 0; j < columnsOut; j++){
                data[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j])  but still get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.writeByte(ByteManager.java:59)
 at com.gc01.FileManager.ByteManager.main(ByteManager.java:88)

Comment: yes.. coz now you can't put any value in variable line. Infact with this approach you don't need a 2D array. You can remove the inner for loop and save the data like this - data[i] = lineString;

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right!Thank you. One final problem. With this new approach I am no longer getting, but the array elements are being written to the file. The file is created, and the .close() method has been successful in the past. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Not getting you. Whats the issue exactly when you say close method has been successful in past?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40214/discussion-between-g-v-and-reece-akhtar)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use an IDE, like Netbeans or Eclipse. Syntactical and semantical problems are marked by the IDE, so you can see where is the problem while you are just editing the code , you don't have to compile always the file. (I want it as a comment, but I can't do it still, so sorry).

Comment: I think now you can :-)

Comment: Thank you, you are a great help :)